# Validación del navegador en formulario desplegable

Tags: javascript, jquery, login, validación, dropdownlist

He implementado un desplegable para el login pero cuando hago el 'submit' con algún campo vacío se me cierra el desplegable y por tanto no aparecen los avisos de validación.

Este es mi desplegable con el formulario:

```
<div class="btn-group dropleft" >
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <spring:message code="master.page.login"/>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu p-4" style="width: 250px;" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <form:form action="j_spring_security_check" modelAttribute="credentials">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
                <form:input id="username" path="username" cssClass="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required="required" />    
                <form:errors class="error" path="username" />
            </div>                                  
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">
                    <img src="images/password.png" style="height:15px;width:auto" />
                </span>
                <form:password id="password" path="password" cssClass="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" required="required"/>  
                <form:errors class="error" path="password" />
            </div>                                  
          </div>          
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Entrar</button>
          <br />
          <br />
          <jstl:if test="${showError == true}">
            <div class="alert alert-danger small" role="alert">
                 ERROR!
            </div>
          </jstl:if>

        </form:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

También he probado añadiendo un 'onclick' en el submit para intentar abrir el desplegable con jQuery pero no parece que el botón funcione como debería. He usado este código, que en cambio, si me ha servido para abrir el desplegable cuando hay un error de credenciales incorrectas al llamar a la BBDD:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(){                
        $(".dropleft").addClass("show");
        $("#dropdownMenu").attr("aria-expanded", "true");
        $(".p-4").addClass("show");             
    }
</script>
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo conseguir visualizar la validación?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado con este script que hace que el dropdown no se cierre con cada click:

```
$(".dropdown-menu").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Gracias a este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502693/validation-of-the-browser-in-dropdown-form/)